# iOs download pictures in photos instead of files

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have a website that provides images and I give users the possibility to download them.
There is an **issue with the iOs users**, the photos that are downloaded thanks to the button I made, go directly to the "Downloads" folder of the iPhone. **(See #1)**
The only way for the photos to go to the right folder is to make a long click on the photo and click on "Add to Photos". **(See #2)**
I would like these photos to be **downloaded to the photo folder** by clicking on the button.
Is there a solution?

#1 / `<a href="photo.jpg" download> Download </a>`

#2 / 
[image]

Thank you